# Issue of async error in custom agent of langchain

Tags: python, streamlit, langchain

I am new to langchain (infact LLMs), I am trying to build a simple custom Agent that can browse though web and answers with memory support in it. The issue is, after it completes search and observation, before it could give final answer on UI, the code execution completes. Thus I don't see result in streamlit chatbot, and when I pass it the second query, it again passes without final answer and throws error "Task was destroyed but it is pending!". [The UI image is attached as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slq1i.png)

The code is:

```
import utils
import os
import streamlit as st
from langchain.chains import LLMChain


from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Tool, ZeroShotAgent
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_community.tools import DuckDuckGoSearchRun
from langchain_community.callbacks import StreamlitCallbackHandler

from langchain_openai import OpenAI

st.set_page_config(page_title="Context Aware Bot", page_icon="")
st.header("Context aware bot")

class CustomAgent:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.openai_api_key = os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
        search = DuckDuckGoSearchRun()
        self.tools = [
            Tool(
                name="Search",
                func=search.run,
                description="useful for when you need to answer questions about current events",
            )
        ]


        prefix = """Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:"""
        suffix = """Begin!"

        Chat History: {chat_history}
        Question: {input}
        {agent_scratchpad}"""

        self.prompt = ZeroShotAgent.create_prompt(
            self.tools,
            prefix=prefix,
            suffix=suffix,
            input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"],
        )

    def custom_agent(self):
        memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
        llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, streaming=True), prompt=self.prompt, verbose=True)
        agent = ZeroShotAgent(llm_chain=llm_chain, tools=self.tools, verbose=True)
        return AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
            agent=agent, tools=self.tools, verbose=True, memory=memory
        )

        
    @utils.enable_chat_history
    def main(self):
        if 'chain' not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.chain = self.custom_agent()
        user_query = st.chat_input(placeholder="Enter Query", key="user_query")
        if user_query:
            with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                with st.spinner("Thinking..."):
                    st_cb = StreamlitCallbackHandler(st.container())
                    response = st.session_state.chain.run(user_query, callbacks=[st_cb])
                    print("Response", response)
                    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = CustomAgent()
    obj.main()
```

CLI:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

Search: useful for when you need to answer questions about current events

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [Search]
Action Input: the input to the action
Observation: the result of the action
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Begin!"

        Chat History: 
        Question: What is weather today in Faisalabad?
        

> Finished chain.

Thought: I should use the Search tool to find the answer.
Action: Search
Action Input: "Weather in Faisalabad today"Error in StreamlitCallbackHandler.on_tool_end callback: RuntimeError('Current LLMThought is unexpectedly None!')

Observation: Pakistan Faisalabad Faisalabad Weather Forecast. Providing a local hourly Faisalabad weather forecast of rain, sun, wind, humidity and temperature. The Long-range 12 day forecast also includes detail for Faisalabad weather today. Faisalabad (Pakistan) weather - Met Office Today 17° 10° Cloudy. Sunrise: 07:00 Sunset: 17:43 M UV Sun 4 Feb 16° 7° Mon 5 Feb 17° 7° Tue 6 Feb 18° 6° Wed 7 Feb 19° 7° Thu 8 Feb 21° 6° Fri 9 Feb... 9 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Saturday 27 Jan max: 25°C min: 12°C 9 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Sunday 28 Jan max: 26°C min: 13°C 6 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Monday 29 Jan max: 26°C min: 13°C 9 Km/h Precipitation in the afternoon the air temperature warms up to +18...+20°C, dew point: +4,04°C; ratio of temperature, wind speed and humidity: Very comfortable; precipitation is not expected, light breeze wind blowing from the north at a speed of 7 km/h, overcast sky; recommended clothing: shoes, closed sandals, kedy, socks, stockings, tights, skirt, pants, t... Today's Weather - Faisalabad, PAK Oct 20, 2023 5:32 PM FAISALABAD -- Feels like -- Hi -- Lo -- -- Live Radar Weather Radar Map WEATHER FORECAST Faisalabad, Punjab, PK Windchill -- Daily Rain -- Dew Point -- Monthly Rain -- Humidity -- Avg. Wind -- Pressure -- Wind Gust -- Sunrise -- Moon -- Sunset -- UV Index Low
Thought:

> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

Search: useful for when you need to answer questions about current events

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [Search]
Action Input: the input to the action
Observation: the result of the action
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Begin!"

        Chat History: 
        Question: What is weather today in Faisalabad?
        
Thought: I should use the Search tool to find the answer.
Action: Search
Action Input: "Weather in Faisalabad today"
Observation: Pakistan Faisalabad Faisalabad Weather Forecast. Providing a local hourly Faisalabad weather forecast of rain, sun, wind, humidity and temperature. The Long-range 12 day forecast also includes detail for Faisalabad weather today. Faisalabad (Pakistan) weather - Met Office Today 17° 10° Cloudy. Sunrise: 07:00 Sunset: 17:43 M UV Sun 4 Feb 16° 7° Mon 5 Feb 17° 7° Tue 6 Feb 18° 6° Wed 7 Feb 19° 7° Thu 8 Feb 21° 6° Fri 9 Feb... 9 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Saturday 27 Jan max: 25°C min: 12°C 9 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Sunday 28 Jan max: 26°C min: 13°C 6 Km/h Precipitation 0 mm Monday 29 Jan max: 26°C min: 13°C 9 Km/h Precipitation in the afternoon the air temperature warms up to +18...+20°C, dew point: +4,04°C; ratio of temperature, wind speed and humidity: Very comfortable; precipitation is not expected, light breeze wind blowing from the north at a speed of 7 km/h, overcast sky; recommended clothing: shoes, closed sandals, kedy, socks, stockings, tights, skirt, pants, t... Today's Weather - Faisalabad, PAK Oct 20, 2023 5:32 PM FAISALABAD -- Feels like -- Hi -- Lo -- -- Live Radar Weather Radar Map WEATHER FORECAST Faisalabad, Punjab, PK Windchill -- Daily Rain -- Dew Point -- Monthly Rain -- Humidity -- Avg. Wind -- Pressure -- Wind Gust -- Sunrise -- Moon -- Sunset -- UV Index Low
Thought:

> Finished chain.
 I now know the final answer.
Final Answer: The weather in Faisalabad today is cloudy with a high of 17°C and a low of 10°C. There is a light breeze and no expected precipitation.

> Finished chain.
Response The weather in Faisalabad today is cloudy with a high of 17°C and a low of 10°C. There is a light breeze and no expected precipitation.
CustomAgent.main


> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

Search: useful for when you need to answer questions about current events

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [Search]
Action Input: the input to the action
Observation: the result of the action
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Begin!"

        Chat History: Human: What is weather today in Faisalabad?
AI: The weather in Faisalabad today is cloudy with a high of 17°C and a low of 10°C. There is a light breeze and no expected precipitation.
        Question: What is humidity level?
        

> Finished chain.
Thought: I should use the search tool to find the current humidity level.
Action: Search
Action Input: "Humidity level in Faisalabad"Error in StreamlitCallbackHandler.on_tool_end callback: RuntimeError('Current LLMThought is unexpectedly None!')

Observation: Sun 4 Feb 16° 7° Mon 5 Feb 17° 7° Tue 6 Feb 18° 6° Wed 7 Feb 19° 7° Thu 8 Feb 21° 6° Fri 9 Feb 21° 7° Sat 10 Feb Today Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Updated: 23:38 (UTC)... Faisalabad is 175 m above sea level and located at 31.42° N 73.15° E. Faisalabad has a population of 2506595. Local time in Faisalabad is 10:47:44 PM PKT. Faisalabad Weather Today (1-3 days): Mostly dry. Warm (max 24°C on Sat afternoon, min 11°C on Fri night). Wind will be generally light. Live weather stations near Faisalabad 8 °C Fog None Wind 500 m Visibility 0 ft Ceiling 1023 hPa 17:35 (7:11h) 3/21 Change 0 ft 1,000 2,000 3,000 4,000 5,000 VV 0 METAR OPFA 250455Z 00000KT 0500 FG VV/// 08/08 Q1023 BECMG 0700 Temperature (°C) 10 8 Visibility (km) 1.2 0 Wind speed (kt) 6 0 QNH (hPa) 1023 1018 METAR Faisalabad International Airport - OPFA/LYP Current Weather Forecast Sun and Moon 16 °C Wind 15 km/h Weather report from station FAISALABAD, Distance: 3 km (17:00 2024/02/03) Weather for the next 24 hours Forecast Su 16 °C Mo 17 °C Tu 18 °C We 18 °C Th 20 °C Fr 21 °C Sa 21 °C Su 26 °C Meteogram Temperature (°C) Precipitation (mm) Gust (km/h) New snow (cm) Hourly Local Weather Forecast, weather conditions, precipitation, dew point, humidity, wind from Weather.com and The Weather Channel
Thought:

> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Have a conversation with a human, answering the following questions as best you can. You have access to the following tools:

Search: useful for when you need to answer questions about current events

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [Search]
Action Input: the input to the action
Observation: the result of the action
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Begin!"

        Chat History: Human: What is weather today in Faisalabad?
AI: The weather in Faisalabad today is cloudy with a high of 17°C and a low of 10°C. There is a light breeze and no expected precipitation.
        Question: What is humidity level?
        Thought: I should use the search tool to find the current humidity level.
Action: Search
Action Input: "Humidity level in Faisalabad"
Observation: Sun 4 Feb 16° 7° Mon 5 Feb 17° 7° Tue 6 Feb 18° 6° Wed 7 Feb 19° 7° Thu 8 Feb 21° 6° Fri 9 Feb 21° 7° Sat 10 Feb Today Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Updated: 23:38 (UTC)... Faisalabad is 175 m above sea level and located at 31.42° N 73.15° E. Faisalabad has a population of 2506595. Local time in Faisalabad is 10:47:44 PM PKT. Faisalabad Weather Today (1-3 days): Mostly dry. Warm (max 24°C on Sat afternoon, min 11°C on Fri night). Wind will be generally light. Live weather stations near Faisalabad 8 °C Fog None Wind 500 m Visibility 0 ft Ceiling 1023 hPa 17:35 (7:11h) 3/21 Change 0 ft 1,000 2,000 3,000 4,000 5,000 VV 0 METAR OPFA 250455Z 00000KT 0500 FG VV/// 08/08 Q1023 BECMG 0700 Temperature (°C) 10 8 Visibility (km) 1.2 0 Wind speed (kt) 6 0 QNH (hPa) 1023 1018 METAR Faisalabad International Airport - OPFA/LYP Current Weather Forecast Sun and Moon 16 °C Wind 15 km/h Weather report from station FAISALABAD, Distance: 3 km (17:00 2024/02/03) Weather for the next 24 hours Forecast Su 16 °C Mo 17 °C Tu 18 °C We 18 °C Th 20 °C Fr 21 °C Sa 21 °C Su 26 °C Meteogram Temperature (°C) Precipitation (mm) Gust (km/h) New snow (cm) Hourly Local Weather Forecast, weather conditions, precipitation, dew point, humidity, wind from Weather.com and The Weather Channel
Thought:

> Finished chain.
 I now know the final answer.
Final Answer: The current humidity level in Faisalabad is 8%.

> Finished chain.
Response The current humidity level in Faisalabad is 8%.
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-81' coro=<AsyncDDGS.__aexit__() running at /home/abdullah/chatbot/streamlit-basic/streamlit-chatbot/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/duckduckgo_search/duckduckgo_search_async.py:46>>
/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:674: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncDDGS.__aexit__' was never awaited
  self._ready.clear()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-65' coro=<AsyncCurl._force_timeout() running at /home/abdullah/chatbot/streamlit-basic/streamlit-chatbot/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/curl_cffi/aio.py:168> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.__wakeup()]>>
```

I tried to go through different docs from langchain, but couldn't get help on it.